# Using another column's value to get the mean in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a very simple dataset with a single Price and Roll columns.

```
           Price  Roll
209265  558180.0     8
209266  558195.0    16
209267  558185.0    18
209268  558120.0    11
209269  558075.0     6
209270  558160.0     6
209271  558140.0    17
209272  558085.0    17
209273  558110.0    14
209274  558160.0    16
209275  558210.0    19
209276  558185.0    11
209277  558180.0    12
209278  558150.0     8
209279  558135.0    15
209280  558135.0    17
209281  558295.0    10
209282  558375.0    18
209283  558520.0    15
209284  558515.0     7
```

What I'm trying to do is to use the value of Roll and get the mean of Price in a rolling window. Something like this:

```
df['Mean'] = df['Price'].rolling(df['Roll']).mean()

ValueError: window must be an integer
```

Is there a quick way for this?

Answer (score 0):

Note that *rolling* requires a **constant** window size, whereas you want
the window size defined **individually** for each row.

So I think the only option is somenthing like this:

Define a function computing the rolling mean price:

```
def getRollPrice(i, roll):
    return df.Price.iloc[i : i + roll].mean()
```

Parameters:

- *i* - integer row index,
- *roll* - *Roll* column from this row.

Then call this function the following way:

```
i = 0
rollPrice = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    rollPrice.append(getRollPrice(i, int(row.Roll)))
    i += 1
df = df.assign(RollPrice=rollPrice)
```

This construction contains at least such optimization that:

- As *iterrows* is used, we have the current row, so we can get the
  value of *Roll* from this row.
- Then *getRollPrice* receives *Roll* as a parameter and its only task
  is to perform a required slice from *Price* column and compute the
  *mean* of it.

Comment: itteration is quite slow. there must be another way using apply() methd but couldn't find it yet.

Comment: I think that this iteration is unavoidable, since you need a slice defined **individually** for each row. At least, my solution is working, contrary to the other solution. Maybe someone else will come up with a quicker solution.